# How to convert dict to RDD in PySpark

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, word2vec

I am learning the Word2Vec Model to process my data.

I using **Spark 1.6.0**.

Using the example of the official documentation explain my problem:

```
import pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec
sentence = "a b " * 100 + "a c " * 10
localDoc = [sentence, sentence]
doc = sc.parallelize(localDoc).map(lambda line: line.split(" "))
model = Word2Vec().setVectorSize(10).setSeed(42).fit(doc)
```

The vectors are as follows:

```
>>> model.getVectors()

{'a': [0.26699373, -0.26908076, 0.0579859, -0.080141746, 0.18208595, 0.4162335, 0.0258975, -0.2162928, 0.17868409, 0.07642203], 'b': [-0.29602322, -0.67824656, -0.9063686, -0.49016926, 0.14347662, -0.23329848, -0.44695938, -0.69160634, 0.7037, 0.28236762], 'c': [-0.08954003, 0.24668643, 0.16183868, 0.10982372, -0.099240996, -0.1358507, 0.09996107, 0.30981666, -0.2477713, -0.063234895]}
```

When I use the `getVectors()` to get the **map** of representation of the words. How to convert it into `RDD`, so I can pass it to KMeans Model?

---

### EDIT:

I did what @user9590153 said.

```
>>> v = sc.parallelize(model.getVectors()).values()
    # the above code is successful.
>>> v.collect()
```

The Spark-Shell shows another problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 771, in collect
port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
File "D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
File "D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 45, in deco
  return f(*a, **kw)
File "D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 29, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 111, in main
File "D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 106, in process
File "D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
  vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "D:\spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1540, in <lambda>
  return self.map(lambda x: x[1])
IndexError: string index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: `model.getVectors().values()` should give you rdd I guess

Comment: I tried `type(model.getVectors().values()`, and it returns <class 'collections.abc.ValuesView'>

Answer (score 0):

Just `parallelize`:

```
sc.parallelize(model.getVectors()).values()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you said. It does convert the map to the RDD, but there is another problem when I `collect` the values. The Spark-shell shows IndexError: string index out of range. More details is above.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelized Collections will help you over here.

```
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) # data here is the collection
val distData = sc.parallelize(data) # converted into rdd
```

For your case:

```
sc.parallelize(model.getVectors()).values()
```

For your doubt:

***The action collect() is the common and simplest operation that returns our entire RDDs content to driver program. 
The application of collect() is unit testing where the entire RDD is expected to fit in memory. As a result, it makes easy to compare the result of RDD with the expected result.
Action Collect() had a constraint that all the data should fit in the machine, and copies to the driver.***

So, you can not perform collect on RDD